Who says understanding physics helps mathematicians? (A reference request) [Take the word "who" literally.]
If I wanted to make a somewhat bold and rather vague claim in print that it is widely acknowledged among mathematicians that knowledge of mechanics (in the sense in which physicists understand that word) sheds light on geometry and perhaps kindred areas of mathematics, and that mathematicians qua mathematicians can benefit from such knowledge, what published papers or books could I cite in support of that statement?

This reminds me of V. I. Arnold.

@SamHopkins Typo. Fixed.

If you go sufficiently far back in time the disciplines are not considered separate. Even around Newton, inventing new math and doing physics were all interconnected ideas.

@SidharthGhoshal : Perhaps, but I'm wondering about more contemporary "wide acknowledgements."

@SidharthGhoshal : If you're talking about going far back in time, here is a very elegant application of mechanics to geometry: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/407823/results-with-short-advanced-proofs-or-long-elementary-proofs/428131#428131

Google will find plenty of answers to this question.  I don’t think it is appropriate for MO, and I’ve voted to close.

A somewhat tangent comment: I believe, traditionally, in several places in Eastern Europe (read, former Eastern Bloc) the mechanics research departments were (maybe some of them still are?) parts of mathematical institutes or at least closely related to them in some way. This is still reflected in the names of many of them, e.g. "Institute for mathematics, physics and mechanics" or "Institute for mathematics and mechanics" and similar.

Spivak wrote a textbook, Physics for Mathematicians. Maybe you could find a good quote in that book.

Do lecture notes posted to the internet count as published books? The introduction to Jared Wunsch's lecture notes on Mechanic for Mathematicians expreswses some of the sentiments you are after. Available at https://sites.math.northwestern.edu/~jwunsch/mechanics.lecturenotes.pdf

Have you seen https://mathoverflow.net/questions/51395/a-soft-introduction-to-physics-for-mathematicians-who-dont-know-the-first-thing ?

@AndyPutman I don't agree that Google will find plenty of answers to this question, especially if we take the question literally: explicit claims that knowledge of mechanics (as opposed to physics more generally) benefiting mathematicians qua mathematicians. Take symplectic geometry. It's easy to find quotes that symplectic geometry originated with the study of classical mechanics and that it is useful for attacking physics problems. But can you find a quote that says that mathematicians qua mathematicians doing research in symplectic geometry will benefit from studying mechanics?

@TimothyChow: Doesn’t it seem trivial that knowing the origins of a subject is useful?  That’s hardly enough meat for a MO question.  And as the answers we have gotten show, what this question is really going to attract are the usual “inspirational quotes” about how amazing physics is.

I think the answer to this is both person dependent and research field dependent. Some fields of physics may offer an impetus to develop or extend an existing math concepts. Some mathematicians may be motivated by discovering applications in the realm of physics. But many others may not be affected in the least regardless of the relevance of "their" branch of math study to some area of physics. Human motivation is a highly varied and subtle thing. Mathematicians' motivation no less so.

[before it was converted to a comment] @Trunk This is not an answer to the question (which is not asking for a general discussion of the place of physics in math research, but for quotes to that effect from famous mathematicians).

@AndyPutman I agree that none of the answers so far seem to answer the question. But I still think the question itself is a reasonable one. I don't think it's trivial that knowing the origins of a subject is useful. It's nice, but does it really help you prove theorems (which is what I take a "mathematician qua mathematician" to be trying to do)?

@TimothyChow: Chapter 1.1 of McDuff-Salamon (the standard textbook on symplectic geometry) is literally called “Hamiltonian Mechanics”.  I think it really is a cliche that people working in that field should know something about mechanics.  More generally, I think that collecting quotes from famous people about the importance of a field is a form of hero-worship that is inappropriate for MO.

It seems no one has yet brought up Yau. Recently he gave some talks/wrote a book on the "Gravity of Math" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IT_TtCGBVVk&ab_channel=TheShawPrize, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2eKtYXpxHO0&ab_channel=Rak-KyeongSeong emphasizing the role of physics in modern geometry

With regard to criticisms expressed here about "the usual inspirational quotes", note that one can be more specific than Atiyah's praise of Witten.  Witten's physical intuitions led him to formulate the Seiberg-Witten equations, which amounted to a revolution in (mathematical) gauge theory, in particular vastly simplifying the proofs of some of Donaldson's results.  Many people have written about this, and I have a text about this https://u.cs.biu.ac.il/~katzmik/diagonalisation.pdf and https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/224394/what-is-the-physical-motivation-of-seiberg-witten-theory

I remember hearing Karen Uhlenbeck say interesting things in this direction a long time ago, but I do not have time to search for any records about that just now.

@TimothyChow, note that Courant and Ruelle specifically mentioned mechanics; see this answer.  So the OP has been answered.

The title says physics, but the question says mechanics.

@MikhailKatz Nice. I upvoted your answer.

Quoting the first two paragraphs of V. I. Arnol'd, On teaching mathematics, Uspekhi Mat. Nauk 53 (1998) 229-234, translated to English in Russian Math. Surveys 53 (1998) 229-236 (a transcription may also be found here if you want to go around the paywall):

Mathematics is a part of physics. Physics is an experimental science, a part of natural science. Mathematics is the part of physics where experiments are cheap.
The Jacobi identity (which forces the altitudes of a triangle to meet in a point) is an experimental fact in the same way as the fact that the earth is round (that is, homeomorphic to a ball). But it can be discovered with less expense.


Does Arnol'd explain why the Jacobi identity forces this geometric consequence?

Unfortunately he doesn't, at least not in this reference... this specific fact refers to the Jacobi identity for the cross (vector) product in $\mathbb{R}^3$. A proper outline of this argument can be found e.g. in https://khudian.net/Etudes/Geometry/jacidentandheights2.pdf

Re, thanks!  I had figured that must be the Jacobi identity in question, but it hadn't occurred to me that the relevant triple cross products would lie back in the original plane, so I hadn't been sure how to interpret it.

Triple cross products always do in the case of three non-collinear but linearly dependent vectors, that's the point.

It is interesting that the quote in the link in another answer by Jacobi indicates that he does not entirely concur.

Michael Atiyah, On the Work of Edward Witten:

In his hands physics is once again providing a rich source of
inspiration and insight in mathematics. Of course physical insight
does not always lead to immediately rigorous mathematical proofs but
it frequently leads one in the right direction, and technically
correct proofs can then hopefully be found.

Leonardo da Vinci:

Mechanics is the paradise of the mathematical sciences because by
means of it one comes to the fruits of mathematics.


Besides Witten, I would add Isaac Newton and Richard Feynman

@Jorge, no doubt, but I think OP wants citations, not just names.

This does not answer the very specific question asked by the OP (actually, what Atiyah is saying here is quite different to what was requested by the OP).

Note also my comment here.

Saunders Mac Lane:

The recent fruitful interchange of ideas (connections, fiber bundles, etc.) with physics (quantum gravity and all that) has been a decided stimulus and a source of new ideas and reapplication of old ones.  (page 192)

He continues by pointing out: "It's great, but involves some of the current weaknesses of physics" and elaborates further on this point.  The source is

Atiyah, Michael; Borel, Armand; Chaitin, G. J.; Friedan, Daniel; Glimm, James; Gray, Jeremy J.; Hirsch, Morris W.; Mac Lane, Saunders; Mandelbrot, Benoit B.; Ruelle, David; Schwarz, Albert; Uhlenbeck, Karen; Thom, René; Witten, Edward; Zeeman, Christopher Responses to: A. Jaffe and F. Quinn, "Theoretical mathematics: toward a cultural synthesis of mathematics and theoretical physics'' [Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. (N.S.) 29 (1993), no. 1, 1–13]. Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. (N.S.) 30 (1994), no. 2, 178–207. doi:10.1090/S0273-0979-1994-00503-8, arXiv:math/9404229

In the same collection, David Ruelle writes:

One point that perhaps deserves being stressed is the usefulness of cultural
cross-fertilization in mathematics. Feigenbaum's cultural background in theoretical
physics has allowed him to discover a new generic bifurcation of smooth
dynamical systems, which would not have been encountered soon by following
standard mathematical paths. Similarly, the physical ideas of equilibrium statistical
mechanics have richly contributed to the mathematical theory of smooth
dynamical systems (with the concepts of entropy, Gibbs states, etc., see my
note in BAMS(NS) 19 (1988), 259-268.) (page 197).

Richard Courant wrote:

... the life blood of our science rises through
its roots; these roots reach down in endless ramification deep
into what might be called reality, whether this "reality" is
mechanics, physics, biological form, economic behavior, geodesy, or,
for that matter, other mathematical substance already in the realm of
the familiar.  (Courant as quoted in Carrier, G.; Courant, R.; Rosenbloom, P.; Yang, C.; Greenberg, H.  "Applied Mathematics: What is Needed in Research and Education."  SIAM Rev., 4(4) (1962), 297--320.)


Perhaps it is correct that this opinion is "widely acknowledged" but it is not unanimous.
Here I collected some statements of some prominent mathematicians related to this question.
Some of those statements are quoted here:

Profound study of nature is the most fertile source of mathematical discoveries.
(J. Fourier, Analytic theory of heat, 1830)


It is true that Mr. Fourier had the opinion that the principal purpose of mathematics was the benefit of the society and the explanation of phenomena of nature; but a philosopher like he should know that the sole purpose of science is the honor of the human mind, and under this title, a question about numbers is as valuable as a question about the system of the world.
(C. G. Jacobi, Letter to Le Gendre, 1830)


In practice this is of course not at all important, because it is negligible for the largest triangle on earth that can be measured; however the dignity of science requires that we understand clearly the nature of this inequality...
(Gauss, in a letter to a friend on a correction of .001" in the measurement of triangles on the earth surface).


It is completely clear to me which conditions caused the gradual decadence of mathematics, from its high level some 100 years ago, down to the present hopeless nadir. Degeneration of mathematics begins with the ideas of Riemann, Dedekind and Cantor which progressively repressed the reliable genius of Euler, Lagrange and Gauss. Through the influence of textbooks like those of Hasse, Schreier and van der Waerden, the new generation was seriously harmed, and the work of Bourbaki finally dealt the fatal blow.
(C. L. Siegel, Letter to A. Weil, 1959. German original is cited in the lecture of H. Grauert, in: Mathematics and Theoretical Physics, ch 1993, ed.: Minaketan Behara, Rudolf Fritsch, Rubens G. Lintz, W. de Gruyter, 1995.)
What would Siegel write today?


All mathematics is divided into three parts: cryptography (paid for by CIA, KGB and the like), hydrodynamics (supported by manufacturers of atomic submarines) and celestial mechanics (financed by military and other institutions dealing with missiles, such as NASA).
(V. Arnold, in: Mathematics: Frontiers and Perspectives, AMS 2000)


You cannot have both. I mean a fish having a meeting one billion years ago under the water and saying: "We are fish, we have all this power, now it is time to conquer the land". But you cannot conquer the land while remaining fish. You can't go to the real world remaining mathematicians; that's absurd. Either you study real problems in the real world - it's a remarkable intellectual challenge, or you remain a mathematician.
(M. Gromov, Dead Sea discussions, in: GAFA 2000. Visions in Mathematics)


The first of these statements, by Fourier, seems to be exactly what the OP is looking for!

These are great quotes. Why not paste them into your MathOverflow answer, rather than putting them on a separate linked webpage? More people will read them if they don't have to leave MO.

@Vincent Is it? The quote from Fourier sounds pretty generic and non-specific; cf. Andy Putman's comments under the question, and also the comment by Sam Hopkins under Trunk's answer (now converted to a comment).

The quote by Fourier is specific imo: he is saying that the deepest mathematical insights always come from studying physical problems.

@HollisWilliams Hardly specific enough for the purposes of the question, which is about how mechanics in particular informs geometry; to me it's along the very general lines of Andy Putman's "And as the answers we have gotten show, what this question is really going to attract are the usual “inspirational quotes” about how amazing physics is." (Also I find your assertion of specificity here at odds with your comment below Carlo Beenakker's answer.)

@ToddTrimble, it is clear from the title the OP is about physics in general and mechanics is mentioned in the body of the question as an example.

@MikhailKatz No, it's not clear. Titles, being short, cannot and should not be relied upon as to what an OP is truly asking; as experience shows, they are often an inaccurate indicator. Always go to the body of the text to find out what the OP is really asking. But, even if you happen to be right in this particular instance, then that would only make the question much poorer for MO (and I don't think there would be much to stop me from voting to close).

Does "mechanics" include "statistical mechanics"? If so, then Ruelle's comment provides an answer to your interpretation of the OP. @Todd

I don't know, but I'll give you an upvote anyway.

@Hollis Williams: This short citation of Fourier, is just a brief conclusion of what he actually says in the long introduction to his book.

Mark Levi's book The Mathematical Mechanic: Using Physical Reasoning to Solve Problems  is full of concrete examples of applying physical intuition in geometry, including even a proof of Gauss Bonnet theorem.
Eugene Wigner wrote that "... the mathematical formulation of the physicist's often crude experience leads in an uncanny number of cases to an amazingly accurate description of a large class of phenomena."
Riemann in his habiltation lecture  refers to the physical experience both at the large and small scales as a source of development for geometry: "A decision upon these questions can be found only by starting from the structure of phenomena that has
been approved in experience hitherto, for which Newton laid the foundation, and by modifying this structure
gradually under the compulsion of facts which it cannot explain". One could say that he was anticipating developments which we know today as quantum mechanics and general relativity.
Finally one might even cite Newton's Principia, which of course is as much about physics as it is about math, or what was called "natural philosophy" at the time. It is clear that Newton's physical intuition guided the development of Calculus. If anyone tried to ask him whether he was a mathematician or physicist, I think that he would be mystified by the question. He wrote that "The description of right lines and circles, upon which geometry is founded, belongs to mechanics", which indicates that physics and geometry have been interlinked all the way back to Euclid.

I think the last paragraph on Mark Levi may answer the question, provided that Mark Levi is a mathematician (I haven't checked).  @SamHopkins  Perhaps this paragraph should be placed first instead of last.

Mark Levi is at the Math Department at Penn State, which certainly qualifies him as a "mathematician".
